# How to bind href to a resource?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I have a `<a id="myId">test</a>` and I want to bind the `href` attribute to **/resources/myUrl**

I've tried:

```
<a data-win-res="{attributes: {'href' : '/resources/myUrl'}}" id='myId'>test</a>
```

and:

```
<a data-win-res="{href : '/resources/myUrl'}" id='myId'>test</a>
```

is there any way to put my resource in `href` or to bind the event click?

[Quickstart: Using string resources (Windows Store apps using JavaScript and HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465254.aspx)

Comment: What happens in the first example? Using the document inspector in VS, what has happened to the tag after calling `WinJS.Resources.processAll();`

Comment: Thanks, but I used `<a onclick="clickOnDefaultAd()" id='myId'>test</a>` and in the function I used `R.getString("/resources/myUrl");` to get the resource

Answer (score 0):

you can do this pretty simple in jquery:

```
$('#myid').attr('href', '/resources/myUrl');
```

Comment: Yes like this: `$('#myid').attr('href', R.getString("/resources/myUrl"));` but I'm not using `jquery` and I wanted to do it on html tag directly. Thanks!